# Using new Date on value of an <input type="date" />

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert the value of an `<input type="date" />` to an actual Javascript Date object. The example is below

```
new Date($('#myInput').val()); //where value of myInput is '2011-01-01'
```

turns out to be

```
Fri Dec 31 2010 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

It appears that the Date is convert from UTC to EST (I think). Is there anyway to prevent this conversion????

example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2t2m8/)

Comment: No, JS `Date` values cannot be converted. It is just output with the users timezone if you use the default `toString` method. The value itself is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Date.prototype.toUTCString` to convert your locale-specific date to UTC

```
(new Date($('#myInput').val())).toUTCString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ver date = new Date(document.getElementById('myinput').value);
date.setTime(date.getTime()+date.getTimezoneOffset()*60000);
```

Alternatively, use the `getUTC*()` functions.

Comment: Yes, one should always use the UTC functions for UTC instead of wrong date values.

Comment: This answer looks correct.  Additionally, the first line can be "var date = document.getElementById('myinput').valueAsDate;"

Comment: @int32_t: No, it sets the date to a wrong value. It only *appears* right since you use the wrong output method as well.